# SPFX with Angular - Not able to use service in component ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, service, spfx

I have created a project using SharePoint SPFX framework and added necessary packages required for Angular (6.0 or 7.0) typescript. It seems Angular is working in my spfx webpart but when I am trying to create a service using Angular, I am not able to use the methods available in the service from component.ts file. Though no errors are being shown in the project, the method declared in the service is coming as undefined when I am trying to use in the component.ts file

**app.service.ts**

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export interface IDataService {
    getTitle(webUrl:string):string;
}
@Injectable()
export class SharePointService {
     constructor() {}     
     public getTitle(webUrl:string):string {
       return webUrl;
     }
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import {IWebPartContext} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base'; 
import { IDataService } from './app.service';

@Component({  
  selector: 'my-spfx-app',  
  template: `<h3>Welcome to SPFx {{name}}!!</h3><p>{{serviceProp}}</p>`
})  
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {  
    public name: string = '';  
    public context:IWebPartContext;
    public serviceProp:string = "";
    constructor(private dataService: IDataService){  
    }  

   public  ngOnInit() {
        this.context= window["webPartContext"];  
        this.name= this.context.pageContext.user.displayName;        
        this.serviceProp = this.dataService.getTitle("Angular Service Testing");
    }  
}
```

**Output**

---

Welcome to SPFx User1

Data is not coming to `serviceProp` variable. Please help us

Comment: Your `SharePointService` class doesn't implement `IDataService` and if you want to use `interface` as dependency injector you would have to add that to your providers and tell it to use `SharePointService`

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the class as the type instead of the interface

```
private dataService: SharePointService
```

and don't forget to provide the service either in the root module or in the feature module that contains the component

```
`@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root' })`
```